# NHibernate: Sorting result by children (of children...) properties

Tags: sql, hibernate, nhibernate

I am trying to build a generic solution to a problem that is probably much more complicated than I realize.

For simplicity, consider that I have the following interface:

```
PagedResult<T> ToPagedResult<T>(this ICriteria, criteria, string sortName);
```

sortName is ideally a json-style path of access.  E.g : Registration.Class.Curriculum.Description, where description is the property that we want to sort on.

In the case where I want to sort on a property of Class, I have been successful with the following:

```
ICriteria pageCriteria = criteria.CreateCriteria("Class", "Class").AddOrder(Order.Desc(sortName));
```

In this case, sortName might equal "Class.Name".

Now, is there a way where I could arbitrarily allow sorting on deeper children?

Answer (score 0):

```
ICriteria pageCriteria = criteria
    .CreateCriteria("Class", "Class")
    .CreateCriteria("Class.Foo", "Foo")
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Foo.Bar"));
```